# Add Polygon programmatically in Leaflet L.Draw plugin

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Is there a way to add a polygon programmatically using the Leaflet draw plugin? https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw

For example: click a button and add a square that can be edited by the plugin.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need to add your polygon (or whatever other layer that you want to be editable) to the Feature Group that you pass to the [`edit.featureGroup`](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#editpolyoptions) option of your `L.Control.Draw` control.

```js
var editableLayers = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
  edit: {
    featureGroup: editableLayers
  }
});

// Add a new editable rectangle when clicking on the button.
button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  L.rectangle([
    getRandomLatLng(),
    getRandomLatLng()
  ]).addTo(editableLayers); // Add to editableLayers instead of directly to map.
});
```

Everything that is in that Feature Group can later be edited by clicking on the "Edit layers" button (if that functionality is enabled).

Live demo:

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([48.86, 2.35], 11);

var editableLayers = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
  edit: {
    featureGroup: editableLayers
  },
  draw: false
}).addTo(map);

// Add a new editable rectangle when clicking on the button.
button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  L.rectangle([
    getRandomLatLng(),
    getRandomLatLng()
  ]).addTo(editableLayers); // Add to editableLayers instead of directly to map.
});

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

function getRandomLatLng() {
  return [
    48.8 + 0.1 * Math.random(),
    2.25 + 0.2 * Math.random()
  ];
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#button {
  z-index: 1050;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-+ZaXMZ7sjFMiCigvm8WjllFy6g3aou3+GZngAtugLzrmPFKFK7yjSri0XnElvCTu/PrifAYQuxZTybAEkA8VOA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-draw@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.draw.
css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-draw@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.draw-src.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>

<button id="button">Add editable rectangle</button>
```