# Add Polygon programmatically in ipyleaflet maps drawing control

Tags: python, leaflet, ipyleaflet

Is there a way to add a known polygon to the Draw interface of a leaflet map ?

I search for the `feature_group` property with :

```py
print(m.__dict__)
```

but didn't find anything. I assume I can add one using geojson format I just don't know where.

Comment: Would https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/geo_json.html work for you?

Comment: unfortunately no, I want to create a starting geometry on my map that the user can then manipulate. It's answered in [js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036712/add-polygon-programmatically-in-leaflet-l-draw-plugin) but cannot find anything in python

Comment: So it's not possible with https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/draw_control.html?

Comment: your link is only showing the customization parameters of the DrawControl. I want to programmatically draw something

Comment: Hello @PierrickRambaud, did you find a way to do this? I'm trying to see how the source code of leafmap could help, but I'm unsuccessful for now. Thanks in advance for any update you can provide!